# String Formatting to Decimal is Adding Two Zero's

Tags: python

Why is my whole number adding two zero's at the end? I want to convert 104184.04 to 104,184.04 but my output is 10,418,404.00

code

```
print("{:,.2f}".format(int(10418404)))
```

Comment: the two after the dot mean 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: @Aaron i have no dot in my original string, its a whole number. if i do rstrip it turns to 10,418,404. I need it to be 104,184.04

Comment: You're confusing a lot of things here. `.2f` formats a floating point number to two decimal places -> your number has no decimal places (it's an integer after all). You probably want `f'{10418404 / 100:,.2f}'`

Comment: @sophocles yes you are correct it ill give me back 10,418,404 but i need 104,184.04

Comment: The input is an int. not a floating point number. the digits after dot is lost.

Comment: How do you expect Python to magically know where you want the `.` to be in `10418404`? It is just an int. You need to do some manual work to add the dot where you want. Something like [what Stefan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920063/string-formatting-to-decimal-is-adding-two-zeros#comment118291047_66920063)

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the float value to an integer value before passing it to the format function. Effectively the same as this...

```
>>> float_value = 104184.04
>>> print("{:,.2f}".format(float_value))
104,184.04
>>> int_value = int(float_value)
>>> print("{:,.2f}".format(int_value))
104,184.00
```